# Sortable not working in el-table-column with checkbox

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

When i try to sort by using either first or second columns, the rows are sorted except for the checkbox in the last column. Is the last column disjoint based on my code?

```
<el-table :data="items" stripe style="width: 50%">
                <el-table-column prop="email" label="email" sortable></el-table-column>
                <el-table-column prop="username" label="Username" sortable></el-table-column>
                <el-table-column label="Enable">
                    <template slot-scope="scope">
                        <el-checkbox :checked="scope.row.isSelected" @change="toggleEnable(scope.row)"  />
                    </template>
                </el-table-column>
            </el-table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically the DOM isn't changed so Vue doesn't recognize the change. To give Vue a hint so that it can track each node’s identity, and thus reuse and reorder existing elements, you need to provide a unique key attribute for each item. In case of element ui table you should fill the `row-key` attribute. Which is listed in [table-atributes](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table#table-attributes)

Adding the `row-key` will solve your challenge

An alternative way to make it work is replacing the `:checked` by `v-model`. but still it's good to provide the `row-key`